# How to check if a letter is "allowed" on a square in the GADDAG move generation algorithm for scrabble?

Tags: algorithm

In the "A Faster Scrabble Move Generation Algorithm" written by Steven a. Gordon, a move generation algorithm for scrabble is introduced. However, the pseudocode provided was a little confusing.

The move generation algorithm laid out in the paper describes the following process:

start on an anchor square, for each letter on the rack, put it on the anchor square, move leftwards, recording complete words along the way, at each step, look for the delimiter in the arcs, go on the arc for the delimiter, and start moving rightward starting on square right of the anchor, record complete words along the way.

Let's say we have a line with the word "log" in the middle of a row. As I understand it, the square before "l" and the square after "g" would be the two anchor squares of this row (assuming "log" is the only word on the board). However, this doesn't make any sense. The algorithm starts from the anchor, move leftward first, and then move rightward, so in the entire time it's moving leftward, the existing "log" on the board doesn't play any role in move generation, so I can easily end up with things like "happy", which makes "happylog" on the board, which wouldn't be a word. I feel like I'm not understanding this correctly. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor squares also have direction (vertical or horizontal) and a list of allowable tiles for that direction.  If log is horizontal, the anchor square in front of log is vertical and would only allow the letters B, C, F or S (and possibly V is some future lexicons).

For playing through LOG, the anchor square would be the L and the algorithm would have to travers the L O and G through the GADDAG before trying the play any tiles on the rack.  For example if the rack contained the tiles AHOMR, then it could follow the path LOGRAM*OH through the GADDAG to play HOLOGRAM.

Steven Gordon

Comment: Let's say "log" is horizontal, so B, C, F, and S would be the cross set of the square before "L" if I were to play vertically. However, if I were to play horizontally, how many anchor squares would there be on the row? The definition of anchor squares is a little ambiguous. It seems that the definition for anchor squares is "an empty square that's adjacent to a filled square". By that definition, "L", as a filled square, wouldn't be the anchor square. It even says specifically in the paper that "... the first tile in the reverse of the prefix to be played directly on the anchor square."

Comment: Also, can you repeat the process of playing through LOG, but with the lexicon organized as rev(x)#y, instead of x#rev(y)?

Comment: Its been 20 years.  I presented the way the DAGGAD worked,  For The GADDAG, the G would have been the anchor square and the path would have been GOLOH*RAM.

Comment: If the anchor square is actually an occupied square, I assume some kind of check has to be added to see if any new tiles were actually placed?

Comment: Easy enough for the generation algorithm to look to see if there is already a letter on the square.  It has to do that anyway to play through tiles already on the board elsewhere.

Comment: It is all implementation details.  The GADDAG data structure is the same no matter how you choose to implement the Scrabble Player and the Board structure.  You just have to test your code to make sure your implementation choices handles all the possible scenarios.

Comment: Thank you! I'm really surprised to get help from Steve Gordon himself. I have finished my implementation and it's working very well